# Make the matrix symmetric

Tags: r, matrix

I have a matrix:

```
contingency.table.1 <- structure(c(40, 5, 1, 0, 24, 8, 0, 1, 2, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1), .Dim = c(4L, 
4L), .Dimnames = list(col1 = c("0", "1", "2", "3"), col2 = c("0", 
"1", "2", "3")), class = "table")
```

Then, if I meet 0 on the diagonal of the matrix, then I replace it with 1

```
contingency.table.1[row(contingency.table.1) == 
                                              col(contingency.table.1) & contingency.table.1 == 0] <- 1
```

I would like to get a matrix, if there are 0 on the symmetric position, then replace them both with 1

What I want to get:

```
contingency.table.1 <- structure(c(40, 5, 1, 1, 24, 8, 0, 1, 2, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1), .Dim = c(4L, 
4L), .Dimnames = list(col1 = c("0", "1", "2", "3"), col2 = c("0", 
"1", "2", "3")), class = "table")
```

if both zeros are in symmetrical positions, then replace them with 1

Comment: Why are e.g. [4,3] and [3,4] not replaced with 1?

Comment: I need a check, if there are both zeros on symmetrical positions, then replace them with 1

Comment: They are in symmetrical positions and don't get replaced, why? Do you mean just the off diagonal?

Comment: the code I use replaces 0 with 1 only on the diagonal. I'm trying to figure out how to replace zeros at symmetric positions

Comment: Seems you have a confusion. What do you mean by diagonal? Because the 0's you replaced are not on the diagonal. Also as @jay.sf stated, the symmetric 0's of [4,3] and [3,4] have not been replaced by 1

Comment: Yes, apparently I'm confused. I'll try again. I want to replace the symmetric elements in which there are 0 by 1 in my example, these are [4,3] and [3,4]

Comment: As said, you probably mean the _off-diagonal_, see solution [below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74543689/6574038).

Comment: but 4,3 and 3,4 have not been replaced. Also only 1,4 and 4,1 HAVE BEEN REPLACED.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just test where the matrix equals the transposed matrix, and where it equals zero

```r
m <- contingency.table.1  
contingency.table.1[m == t(m) & m == 0] <- 1
```

Result

```r
contingency.table.1
#>     col2
#> col1  0  1  2  3
#>    0 40 24  2  1
#>    1  5  8  1  1
#>    2  1  0  1  1
#>    3  1  1  1  1
```

<sup>Created on 2022-11-23 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: This is not correct. Notice that elements 4,3 and 3,4 have not been replaced

Comment: @onyambu they have been replaced with 1. They were 0 before.

Comment: No they are still not replaced by 1. Only the elements 1,4 and 4,1 are replaced by 1

Comment: @onyambu can you explain what you mean? Before I run my code, `contingency.table.1[4,3]` returns 0 and `contingency.table.1[3, 4]` returns 0 too. After I run my code, contingency.table.1[4,3]` returns 1 and `contingency.table.1[3, 4]` returns 1. Why do you say these elements are not replaced?

Comment: In the expected output, the elements 4,3 and 3,4 should not be replaced. Your code replaces them, yet OP output shows that they should not be replaced

Answer (score 1):

Using a `for` loop.

```
rp <- \(m) {
  stopifnot(diff(dim(m)) == 0L)  ## symmetricity check
  for (i in seq_len(ncol(m)) - 1L) {
    c1 <- n - i
    c2 <- i + 1L
    if (all(c(m[c1, c2], m[c2, c1]) == 0))
      m[c1, c2] <- m[c2, c1] <- 1
  }
  m
}

rp(contingency.table.1)
#     col2
# col1  0  1  2  3
#    0 40 24  2  1
#    1  5  8  1  1
#    2  1  0  1  0
#    3  1  1  0  1
```

Comment: returns an error on `sq`

Comment: @GOGAGOGA Sorry, try now.